# Converting decimal number with negative sign to fixed width string

Tags: r, casting

I would like to convert a decimal coordinate (e.g. -62.54879632547) to a fixed width strings as follows:

negative number -> leading 0

positive number -> leading 1

then 3 digits for the integer part

62 -> 062

2 -> 002

Then 6 digits after the decimal (and removing the decimal)

.54879632547 -> 548796

Final restuls:

-62.54879632547 -> 0062548796 (i.e. 0 062 548796)

How to do that fast and efficient in R?

I have made the following function, but it is quite slow (when used with lapply over millions of values):

```
     formatCoordinate <- function (x) {
      if (!is.na(x)) {
        sign <- ifelse(x < 0, 0, 1)
        castIntergerPart <- function (x) {
          #integer part should be exactly 3 digits with leading zeros if necessary 
          if (abs(x) < 10) {
            intgerPart <- paste0("00", abs(as.integer(x)))

          }else if (abs(x) >=10 & abs(x) < 100) {
            intgerPart <- paste0("0", abs(as.integer(x)))

          }else if (abs(x) >= 100) {
            intgerPart <- paste0(abs(as.integer(x)))
          }
        }

        castDecimalPart <- function(x) {
          s <- toString(x)
          sub(".*?.(.*?);.*", "\\1", s)
          substr(unlist(strsplit(s, split='.', fixed=TRUE))[2], 1, 6)
        }

        formattedCoordinate = paste0(sign, castIntergerPart(x), castDecimalPart(x))  
      }else{
        NA    
      } 
    }
```

any help is appreciated

best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some string formatting and regular expressions. Can deal with vectors of numbers.

```
formatter <- function(x){
  first_part <- ifelse(x < 0 , "0","1")
  second_part <- abs(as.integer(x))
  third_part <- substr(gsub(".+\\.","",as.character(x)),1,6)
  result <- ifelse(!is.na(x),sprintf("%s%03d%s",first_part,second_part,third_part), NA)
  result

}
> formatter(-62.54879632547)
[1] "0062548796"
```

Comment: Many thanks Heroka! Your code is 2X faster. Do you think I can use mclappy with it? I tried the following and it didn't work:  x1 <- runif(1000000, 5.0, 7.5)   ..  t<- mclapply(x1, formatter, m.cores=4 )
Warning message:
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

Comment: I'm not familiar with mclappy. However, formatter(x1) ran in 7 seconds on my machine. Not sure if that's still too slow for you (I often spend more time optimizing code than the time won warrants)

Comment: Thanks again, I was using apply(x1) because my code is one value based, but using formatter(x1) without lapply is 13X faster than my code, which is excellent!

Comment: Hooray! As a note, you can easily add spaces between components if you want by changing the string inside sprintf to `"%s %03d %s"

Comment: The original one is perfect, as I will use the result as a primary key to join different tables